# Create dependent dropdown in django from columns of a database

Tags: html, django, django-models, dropdown

I have set up a model in Django:

```
class Car_list(models.Model):
    car_brand = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car_model_cat = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    car_fuel = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    car_typ = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

And already have put data through a import method and the admin page. Now I want to create a dependent dropdown over all fields. I would be happy if I could do it just for the first two columns.

My question: All tutorials show me that I have to create separate models like one for car_brand and one for car_model_cat. And then have to go via keys. Isn't there another way, cause I have to separate the whole table which is huge?

Can I just make a dependent dropdown out of the data of the whole table?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

download : https://github.com/nicolasbize/magicsuggest/zipball/master

import

```
<link href="assets/magicsuggest/magicsuggest-min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="assets/magicsuggest/magicsuggest-min.js"></script>
```

first dropdown **car_brand**
second dropdown **car_name** (car_model according car_brand)

so first dropdown in user any value select that time selected value (data like id) pass to view side and get data car_model according selected car_barnd. and this data pass to user interface side (template). this format
`[{'id':1,'name':'car_model'},.....]`. this data set into car_name (car_model) dropdown using magicsuggest.

ex:

.html code

```
<input name='car_brand' id='id_car_brand'/>
<input name='car_model' id='id_car_model'/>
```

.js or  side code

```
$("#id_car_brand").change(function() {
   // view side call though ajax and get data
      car_model according car_brand this format [{'id':1,'name':'car_model'},.....]  
   var ms_car_model= $('#id_car_model').magicSuggest();
   ms_car_model.setData([{'id':1,'name':'car_model'},.....]);
});
```

FYI magicsuggest doc : http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html